# Longtail JW Player not starting properly

Tags: jwplayer

I'm trying to get the Longtail JW Player working (for playing .flv files on a website).

**PROBLEM:** *when i press play the audio starts but the video does not*. if i press it again then the video comes in... but that's no good.

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>JW Player for Flash</title>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.registerObject("player","9.0.98","expressInstall.swf");
    </script>

    <object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="468" height="262">
        <param name="movie" value="player-licensed.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="file=Bioshphere-Museum-of-Water.flv&image=preview.jpg" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player-licensed.swf" width="468" height="262">
            <param name="movie" value="player-licensed.swf" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="file=video.flv&image=preview.jpg" />
            <p><a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer">Get Flash</a> to watch this video.</p>
        </object>
    </object>

</body>
</html>
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE**: http://solomongiles.com/mediamar/readme.html

It's been happening to me every time and every way I try to install this bloody player, but when it works it seems to be best thing going. any ideas?

Jon

Comment: JW Player is a flash-based flv player for embeding in webpages, this is in the right place. That said, some code with what you're actually trying would be nice.

Comment: If you're sure that's the case, it's a good job you mentioned it! I still think someone's going to try and close it though...

Comment: Also, if it's a legitimate question that just needs moving, can people not downvote it? It makes it look like a bad question **after** it's moved too.

Comment: Interesting, when I view your site in IE6, I see 2 players - the one on the left lasts 6 secs and only plays audio, the one on the right is 6mins + and plays audio and video. In FF3 I only see the 6 sec one.

Comment: IE6 = fixed this issue. original problem still in effect.

Comment: It is the problem with your video conversion. Check your video frame rate. it might be too low(2fps), if you increase it(ex: 24 fps) then your problem will be solved.